# How can I make products with positive qty out of stock?

Tags: stock, out-of-stock, stock-status

I would like only products that have qty=>5 to be marked as in stock, those that are less than five would be marked as out of stock and they won't be available for sale.

Comment: For Mgento-2 or Magento-1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Magento-2

You can make products with positive qty out of stock from admin setting

```
Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Product Stock Option >> Out-of-Stock Threshold
```

Add 5 to here and check any product with qty value 5. It will auto out of stock.

Comment: thank you! I found that in Magento 1 it is here:  Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Product Stock Option >> Out-of-Stock Threshold

Comment: This is great! This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this on Magento 1 by going to

System-Configuration-Catalog-Inventory-Product Stock Options

And adjusting the value for ' Qty for items status to become out of stock'